# Prevent ssh-agent from starting in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh-agent

I started `ssh-agent` using:

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
ssh-add /path/to/key
```

on one of the servers (Ubuntu 16.04) to allow for `rsync`, and had thought that the session for the `ssh-agent` will expire after logging off.

It did not, and instead it starts up every time I log in, and since the key is shared across a few servers, all of them are now automatically authenticating without requesting for passphrase.

I tried `ssh-agent -k` but that always throws `SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent`.

If I do `ssh-agent` to get the PID, then `sudo kill -9 [PID]`, another `ssh-agent` process starts up with a new PID.

I want to completely turn off `ssh-agent` and prevent it from starting up every time I login for all the affected servers.

Comment: Did you add the `eval $(ssh-agent)` lines to one of your startup files (where)?

Comment: Is this a pure server (no GUI)? if not, have you checked for the possible presence of other authentication agents such as gnome-keyring-ssh?

Comment: @steeldriver, yes this is a pure server without GUI, so everything is access via SSH shell. I don't think there are other authentication agents, tried gnome-keyring-ssh, which returned command not found.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I logged into the SSH via putty and typed "eval $(ssh-agent)" then "ssh-add [path to SSH key]". I did this only on one of my servers, and logins to all other servers using the same key are getting automatically authenticated.

I did not add the command as part of any bash script, just typed both the command, and it worked too well and now ssh-agent keep start in all my logins.

Comment: So, you have machine A (a workstation or like) which you use to log in to machine B (an Ubuntu server)? And also some other servers C, D, E...? I must be missing something, since I can't see how running `ssh-agent` on B would affect logins started from A if you're not running an ssh agent (or `pageant`) on A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `~/.bash_logout`, do

```
eval $(ssh-agent -k)
```

Alternatively, for non-`bash` shells, start `ssh-agent` with

```
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]; then
  ssh-agent myshell
fi
```

where `myshell` is e.g. `dash` or `ksh93` or something else.

Do this in at the very end of your *login shell initialization file*, usually `~/.profile`. The agent will die when you log out.

To clean up a bunch of left-over `ssh-agent` processes that were erroneously started (this will kill *all* of them):

```
$ pkill ssh-agent
```